# Doing feature selection based on non-diagonalized covariance matrix vs on eigenvalues?

Tags: feature-selection

Doing feature selection based on non-diagonalized covariance matrix vs on eigenvalues (that equal the diagonal of diagonalized covariance matrix)?

If the values differ in non-diagonalized covariance matrix, then can it be possible that the feature selection done in these two cases offers different outcomes? Is one of them better than another? Do both approaches retain the differences/ratios between variables/values or do they differ even in that sense?